# How do I configure Yarn as the default package manager for Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, yarnpkg

How do I configure Angular CLI to use Yarn as the default package manager?

Answer (score 25):

As of Angular CLI 6.x the correct command is

```
ng config --global cli.packageManager yarn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```